# Why did Feeds delete my chat message?

Tags: support, bug, chat, chat-flags

I posted a message in [Charcoal HQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) today (to add a new website to SmokeDetector's watchlist) and while it was acknowledged by the bot, it was promptly deleted. The [message history](https://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/54068624/history) says it was deleted by Feeds:

[image]

(I've thought of the possibility that SmokeDetector deleted it as a way of marking it as processed, but it's only a room owner, not a chat moderator. I suspect something obscure/unknown is going on here, but I have no clue.)

Comment: Seems like a new user raised a flag by mistake. https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54068765

Comment: Oh, that's nice :) I can see it in the recent flags too; it got 2 flags and 1 counterflag. AFAIK that's not enough to have the message deleted ...

Comment: ... unless one of said flags was by a moderator, but then I would be suspended as well. It would be nice to have this clarified by a developer.

Comment: As a moderator you can't get suspended. The experiments we did where you were suspended involved changing your parent account.

Comment: My wild guess: when the chat message includes some black listed words, or URL, it requires less flag approvals to get deleted.

Comment: @ShadowWizardisEarForYou what would the blacklisted word be in this case?

Comment: @John taku? ;-)

Comment: Hmmm ... the other flag might be from someone unfamiliar with SmokeDetector (90% of the community) who thought I was actually *promoting* that website ...